# Android Security: Save a private String

Tags: php, android, mysql, string, security

I have a specific Question to Android security.

First, I ill describe my problem:
I want to connect to a Database via PHP. But everybody can extract the Link out of my apk which I use to connect to the PHP File. This leads to the problem: Everybody can manipulate my  Database just by Calling this Link. I want to prevent SQL Injection.

I am searching for a solution to this problem.
My first idea, and probably the most simple, was to Create a totally private String, which is used to authenticate the access of the PHP file. But I have no idea, how i could save such String without having the risk of getting extracted from the Code (e.g. whit a Strings.xml, or simply writing it in my Code).
Is there a simple method, to make a String totally private in my APK (so that nobody can extract it)?
Or has anybody an even better solution?

Answer (score 1):

There's no real security against reverse engineering your app and finding out the "secret" url.

I recommend you to secure that url with some kind of user authentication. the url should be secured no matter which client is trying to access it.

Comment: When a User has to authenticate (for example by giving a username and password) he can easily manipulate the Data too. Doing it this way, i could only react afterwords and restore the unmanipulated data ;( but thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: Sounds like you need to encapsulate your API to the server better. think of every API call as malicious one.

Answer (score 0):

Everything stored in the client can be retrieved/spoofed/etc.  You need to have the client authenticate to the server before running commands against the database.

You need to secure your database against unauthorized access.  Right now it sounds like you are using "security through obscurity" by just hiding the URL.  This is bad practice.  It is only a matter of time until someone finds it who you don't want finding it.  It wouldn't even take a reverse engineering, but simply a glance at router logs.

Also, [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is when someone injects malicious code into a SQL query being crafted by code that doesn't properly sanitize it.  This attack works inside of an authenticated session.  This is something you need to watch out for too, but it is not the risk you described in the question.

Comment: do you have an idea, how i can authenticate the client to the server?

Comment: maybe a tutorial or something? that would be very helpful :)

Comment: @user2167430 there are many different ways to have the client authenticate.  A common way is to supply username and password.  I wouldn't make the database world accessible, but rather I would have a RESTful web service running up front that handles authentication for you and then authenticates itself to the database.